# Integration Testing Django All-Auth Email Confirmation

Tags: django, email, selenium, tdd, django-allauth

I'd like to do some integration testing and I'm stuck on how I should test the email confirmation bit of the sign up process.

My user story is (basically) that a new visitor comes to the site, decides that they want to sign up, confirm their email address and then get redirected to their shiny new profile.

How would I simulate clicking on the link in the email to get redirected to the user profile?

I'm currently using Selenium to conduct my functional/integration testing and to a certain extent the django test suite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two documentation pages have everything you need:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/testing/overview/
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/testing/tools/#email-services

A simple example:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.core import mail

class EmailTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        ## Do something
        pass

    def test_email_content(self):
        ## Do something that triggers an email.
        ## Check the number of emails.
        print(len(mail.outbox))
        ## Check the content of the first email.
        first_email = mail.outbox[0]
        if first_email:
            print(first_email.body)
```

Comment: I had already figured this out but completely forgot to update the question. Full marks, bro!

Comment: Yeah, I imagined...  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You should look up a python way to read emails.

Steps:

1. Find the email
2. Store the link
3. Start up your selenium test, and open up said link
4. Validate that you are on the page

Comment: I can use the django email outbox to count the number of emails but have yet to find a way to access the content of the email...if I can access the content programmatically then life would be good.

Comment: you definitely can do that :) search Google for python read emails. however, that's out of the scope of this question.

Comment: Haven't really been able to find anything of the sort...do you have any possible resources to share?